# Apollo Graphql return result without sending the request

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to create a ApolloLink that, under certain conditions, will not send a request to the server, and instead will immediately return some result.

But I haven't found this possibility in the documentation.
Unless you can cancel the request by throwing an exception.

Is there any opportunity to do create such ApolloLink?